# How do I crop the extra space off of a header?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just got my first paying development job developing a website for a local rapper and I'm pretty nervous.

I'm working on the site logo and navbar at the moment and I've run into a bit of an issue.

This is what I've got so far:

[image: http://imgur.com/kVMm9pD]

What I want is to crop off the extra space to the top and bottom of the "Citi B" text in orange. After getting rid of that unnecessary space, I want to align it to the bottom of the limegreen div.

Here is all related code.

HTML:

```
<div class="title-wrap">
            <div class="title1">
                <h1>Citi B.</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="title2">
                <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Dog Logo">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.title-wrap {
width: 60%;
margin: auto;
background: limegreen;
height: auto;
}

.title1, .title2 {
background: orange;
}

.title1 h1 {
font-size: 6em;
bottom: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
```

Flexbox code:

```
.title-wrap {
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-align-items: flex-end;
}
```

This problem is probably very simple to solve, but I'm drawing a blank for whatever reason. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: your first problem is the dog logo on the right, it is too tall, causing the green above the orange box.

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it by giving it a max-width of 75%.

Comment: also be aware this may look bad on other browsers, such as Firefox and IE, as it seems you have some `-webkit` only css there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem, but I think your problem is about space in top of the page.
You should know that body have a little margin  and you should remove it.
This code maybe can help you.

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Good Luck.